# Plone Portlets Misalligned

Tags: css, alignment, plone, portlet

I have a Plone site that has a portlet displaying the navigation tree.  This is supposed to be on the left side of the page, with the main page display area in the center (and to the right).  Instead, this portlet gets pushed to the bottom of the page, and is stretched across the entire page width (So the "Manage portlets" link spans the whole width of the page, and is at the bottom just above the footer).  I cannot figure out how or why it got like this, nor where the settings are to fix this..?

Comment: The answer below may be right.  Is this a OOTB Plone install?  Have you customized anything?  If so, what?  The answer to this question will depend on the specifics here.

Comment: This is an OOTB install - as mentioned below I have two instances.  One working and one not.  The customizations I've done have been applied to both, except the non-working one had the add-on "PloneFormGen" uninstalled (I can't imagine that would trip it up?)

Comment: I am afraid you will need to do some troubleshooting on your own, then report back here. You should be able to figure out the difference between the two sites using Firebug or some similar tool. Any number of things can cause styles to break on a Plone site, and it's simply not practical (nor is it in the spirit of StackOverflow) for contributors to speculate on the cause, without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a skinning issue. What theme are you using?

In Plone 4, you might start by looking at the main_template.pt of your theme under portal_skins. Look for `<tal:block replace="structure provider:plone.leftcolumn"/>`
There you can see any CSS that's applied to your leftcolumn portlets.

If you're not already using Firebug, you should try it out. It's pretty helpful in figuring out why your stuff is out of whack.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the structure provider isn't incorrect.  I have two instances, one working fine and the other is off.  I've compared the two files (main_template.pt) and there are no differences between the working one and the not working one...

Comment: @blacksheep: sounds like a CSS issue then.